# Get and check WooCommerce user subscription end date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, woocommerce-subscriptions

How i can display end date subscribe for user ?
I have id user and i need date for end subscribe

I try use `$WC_Subscription` and `wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id)` but this method throws an error.

How I can use `$WC_Subscription`?

Comment: Please add more details like the exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id)` is not a method but a function. `WC_Subscription` is the main Class for subscriptions.

The main issue in your approach is that `wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id)` function return **an array** of user subscriptions, but not the subscription object itself, as a user can have multiple subscriptions.

To get the end date from a `WC_Subscription` object, you will use [`get_date('end')` method](https://woo.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-3).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77455937/show-total-count-of-expired-woocommerce-subscriptions-on-custom-admin-page/77456307#77456307) here is the correct way to get, for a user, his subscription's end date, without throwing errors.

1. You can use a `foreach` loop to iterate through the user subscriptions:

```php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Loop through user subscriptions
foreach ( wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id) as $subscription ) {
    $end_date = $subscription->get_date('end');

    if (  ! empty($end_date) ) {
        echo '<p>End date: ' . $end_date . '</p>';
    }
}
```

2. You can use `current()` or `reset()` functions to get the subscription object, for only **one subscription**:

```php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Get the subscription object (for a unique subscription)
$subscription = current( wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id) );

$end_date = $subscription->get_date('end');

if (  ! empty($end_date) ) {
    echo '<p>End date: ' . $end_date . '</p>';
}
```